# Local storage check if key exists on partial match

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have an ionic app and using Capacitor storage. It uses local storage to store the user details. The key created for username is dynamic but has the LastAuthUser appended at the end.

How can I get the '237498274ksajfdkjsahf.LastAuthUser' from the localStorage?

Is there a way to look for keys that contains 'LastAuthUser' ignoring the prefix?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.entries(localStorage)` to get all the key value pairs from localStorage. Then, find the one you're looking for with the `find` method.

```js
const storage = Object.entries(localStorage);
const found = storage.find(([key]) => /.*LastAuthUser$/.test(key));

console.log(found[0], found[1]);
```